# How to extract the UI element from data template?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, frameworkelementfactory

I used the following code to create data template items:

```
 FrameworkElementFactory textCtrl = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));            
        Binding binding1 = new Binding();
        string path = "Syncfusion";
        binding1.Path = new PropertyPath(path);
        textCtrl.SetValue(TextBox.TextProperty,binding1);
        Binding binding2 = new Binding();
        string path2 = "Text1";
        binding2.Path = new PropertyPath(path2);
        textCtrl.SetValue(TextBox.NameProperty, binding2);
        DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate();
        dt.VisualTree = textCtrl;
```

How to get the text box from the data template..?

I tried the following links
[Link 1](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/frameworkelementfactory-basic-usage-174324.aspx)

[Link 2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/6ddde336-c7dd-46c3-b163-c8e093d9fd01)

But I did not get the things correctly...

I used the below code in xaml

```
<DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding CellBoundValue}" gridcommon:VisualContainer.WantsMouseInput="False"/>
 </DataTemplate>
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: why are you doing datatemplates in procedural code? also, what do you want the textbox for?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Microsoft does not recommend to use the FrameworkElementFactory, it may get deprecated some times (not sure about this).

But if you want to do it anyway, you must apply your DataTemplate to create instances of controls declared in the DataTemplate. You can do this for example with a ContentControl or an ItemsControl.